# Correcting TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python, arrays, function

Hi I am new to python and I am trying to numerically integrate a differential equation d/dt(θi) =ωi +summation of j( Kij sin(θj −θi)), i=1,...,N.

Kuramoto model:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint



def kuramoto(theta,t):
        N = len(t)
        w = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4])
        K = np.random.rand(N,N)
    
        for i in range (0,N-1):
            sum =  K[i][i+1]*np.sin(theta[i+1]-theta[i])
            sum = sum + K[i][i-1]*np.sin(theta[i-1]-theta[i])
            theta_dot = w[i] + (1/N)*sum
            return theta_dot

t = np.linspace(0,40,40)
theta0 = [(0.2,0.4,0.3,1.2)]
for theta0 in [(0.2,0.4,0.3,1.2)]:
    y_true = odeint(kuramoto,theta0,t)
    plt.plot(t,y_true,'r-')
```

However, I keep getting an error `TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()`.  Can someone please help me correct this error?

Comment: Hey! Can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Your code does not work in its current state, there is some missing indentations.

Comment: Ohh okay, I have edited it and pasted the code from spyder here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error -
*TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()*,
which means that the object you are trying to calculate the length of doesn't;t have a lenght
Here, on line 5 the code is `len(t)` and "t" here is a float meaning a decimal number. Which you can't calculate length of.

In the function

```
def kuramoto(theta,t):
        N = len(t)
        w = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4])
        K = np.random.rand(N,N)
```

the 2nd parameter- "t" is not the array that you pass during the function call,
if you print "t" in the function defination it will print a float value, hence the TypeError when tried to calculate lenght.
There is one thing you can do here, If the lenght of the array yoou pass remains constant, you can hard code it.

If that isn't a solution then try to get a better understanding of the function, what it is doing, I have printed "t" for you to understand what is being passed in it.
Try this code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# function that returns dy/dt
def model(y,t):
    print("t=",t)
    k = 0.3
    dydt = -k * y
    return dydt

# initial condition
y0 = 5

# time points
t = np.linspace(0,20)

# solve ODE
y = odeint(model,y0,t)

# plot results
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('y(t)')
plt.show()
```

You'll get an idea what is stored in "t"

Refrence: https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/SolveDifferentialEquations

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to define a function but instead, I defined it inside a for loop. I have edited it.

Comment: I have defined t with np.linspace to get an array and then I want to take the length of this array for my iteration

Comment: Changed the answer accordingly, check it out. Upvote if it helps.